# Determining a threshold value for a bimodal distribution via KMeans clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'd like to find a threshold value for a bimodal distribution.  For example, a bimodal distribution could look like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(45)
n = 1000; b = n//10; i = np.random.randint(0,2,n)
x = i*np.random.normal(-2.0,0.8,n) + (1-i)*np.random.normal(2.0,0.8,n)
_ = plt.hist(x,bins=b)
```

[image: bimodal_histogram]

An attempt to find the cluster centers did not work, as I wasn't sure how the matrix, h, should be formatted:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
h = np.histogram(x,bins=b)
h = np.vstack((0.5*(h[1][:-1]+h[1][1:]),h[0])).T  # because h[0] and h[1] have different sizes.
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(h)
```

I would expect to be able to find the cluster centers around -2 and 2.  The threshold value would then be the midpoint of the two cluster centers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing to me, so please let me know if I've interpreted it incorrectly. I think you are basically trying to do 1D kmeans, and try to introduce frequency as a second dimension to get `KMeans` to work, but would really just be happy with `[-2,2]` as the output for the centers instead of `[(-2,y1), (2,y2)]`.

To do a 1D kmeans you can just reshape your data to be `n` of 1-length vectors (similar question: [Scikit-learn: How to run KMeans on a one-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416408/scikit-learn-how-to-run-kmeans-on-a-one-dimensional-array))

code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(45)
n = 1000;
b = n//10;
i = np.random.randint(0,2,n)
x = i*np.random.normal(-2.0,0.8,n) + (1-i)*np.random.normal(2.0,0.8,n)
_ = plt.hist(x,bins=b)

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
h = np.histogram(x,bins=b)
h = np.vstack((0.5*(h[1][:-1]+h[1][1:]),h[0])).T  # because h[0] and h[1] have different sizes.

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(x.reshape(n,1))
print kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

output:

```
[[-1.9896414]
 [ 2.0176039]]
```