# How to adjust kMeans clustering sensitivity?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have the following dataset:

```
        node        bc cluster
1    russian  0.457039       1
48       man  0.286875       1
155    woman  0.129939       0
3        bit  0.092721       0
5      write  0.065424       0
98       age  0.064347       0
97     escap  0.062675       0
74      game  0.062606       0
```

Then I perform kMeans clustering by `bc` value to separate the nodes into two different groups. Right now with the code below I get the result above (the clustering result is in the `cluster` column).

```
    bc_df = pd.DataFrame({"node": bc_nodes, "bc": bc_values})
    bc_df = bc_df.sort_values("bc", ascending=False)
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(bc_df[['bc']])
    bc_df.loc[:,'cluster'] = km.labels_
    print(bc_df.head(8))
```

Which is pretty good, but I would like it to work slightly differently and to select the first 4 nodes into the first cluster and then the other ones in the 2nd one, because they are more similar to each other.

Can I do some adjustment to kMeans or maybe you know another algorithm in `sklearn` that can do that?

Comment: from my eyes , 3rd and 4th value is more close to 0.065..

Comment: yes, but then everything from the 5th value is more or less the same...

Comment: If you only have two groups maybe you can try not using sklearn ..

Comment: I have an idea, but can I ask fisrt, the `bc` values. where did you get those?

Comment: @chitown88 this is calculated before — it's the betweenness centrality measure for the nodes.

Comment: cool. and you're just looking to split into 2 groups?

Comment: @chitown88 yes.

Comment: @chitown88 i want the more similar ones to be grouped together, while the outliers are separate. like the elbow of the distribution curve.

Comment: great, give me a minute or two, I have a solution. just need to clean it up a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it looks like you are wanting is a clustering on 1-dimensional data. One way to to work this out is to use the Jenks Natural Breaks (google it to get an explanation of it).

I didn't write this function (lots of credit goes to @Frank with his solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416408/scikit-learn-how-to-run-kmeans-on-a-one-dimensional-array))

**Given your dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
['russian',  0.457039],
['man',  0.286875],
['woman',  0.129939],
['bit',  0.092721],
['write',  0.065424],
['age',  0.064347],
['escap',  0.062675],
['game',  0.062606]], columns = ['node','bc'])
```

**Code with Jenks Natural Break Function:**

```
def get_jenks_breaks(data_list, number_class):
    data_list.sort()
    mat1 = []
    for i in range(len(data_list) + 1):
        temp = []
        for j in range(number_class + 1):
            temp.append(0)
        mat1.append(temp)
    mat2 = []
    for i in range(len(data_list) + 1):
        temp = []
        for j in range(number_class + 1):
            temp.append(0)
        mat2.append(temp)
    for i in range(1, number_class + 1):
        mat1[1][i] = 1
        mat2[1][i] = 0
        for j in range(2, len(data_list) + 1):
            mat2[j][i] = float('inf')
    v = 0.0
    for l in range(2, len(data_list) + 1):
        s1 = 0.0
        s2 = 0.0
        w = 0.0
        for m in range(1, l + 1):
            i3 = l - m + 1
            val = float(data_list[i3 - 1])
            s2 += val * val
            s1 += val
            w += 1
            v = s2 - (s1 * s1) / w
            i4 = i3 - 1
            if i4 != 0:
                for j in range(2, number_class + 1):
                    if mat2[l][j] >= (v + mat2[i4][j - 1]):
                        mat1[l][j] = i3
                        mat2[l][j] = v + mat2[i4][j - 1]
        mat1[l][1] = 1
        mat2[l][1] = v
    k = len(data_list)
    kclass = []
    for i in range(number_class + 1):
        kclass.append(min(data_list))
    kclass[number_class] = float(data_list[len(data_list) - 1])
    count_num = number_class
    while count_num >= 2:  # print "rank = " + str(mat1[k][count_num])
        idx = int((mat1[k][count_num]) - 2)
        # print "val = " + str(data_list[idx])
        kclass[count_num - 1] = data_list[idx]
        k = int((mat1[k][count_num] - 1))
        count_num -= 1
    return kclass






# Get values to find the natural breaks    
x = list(df['bc'])

# Calculate the break values. 
# I want 2 groups, so parameter is 2.
# If you print (get_jenks_breaks(x, 2)), it will give you 3 values: [min, break1, max]
# Obviously if you want more groups, you'll need to adjust this and also adjust the assign_cluster function below.
breaking_point = get_jenks_breaks(x, 2)[1]

# Creating group for the bc column
def assign_cluster(bc):
    if bc < breaking_point:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

# Apply `assign_cluster` to `df['bc']`    
df['cluster'] = df['bc'].apply(assign_cluster)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
      node        bc  cluster
0  russian  0.457039        1
1      man  0.286875        1
2    woman  0.129939        1
3      bit  0.092721        0
4    write  0.065424        0
5      age  0.064347        0
6    escap  0.062675        0
7     game  0.062606        0
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! Is it possible to change its sensitivity, so that it lowers the threshold? Or shall I then just try to split it into more groups? Also, can you remember where approximately you got it from?

Comment: I don't think you can lower the sensitivity. I suppose sure, if you adjust the number of breaks, that could do the trick. But then you might just need to play around with it to see where it puts the breaks

Comment: found it. I'll post it in the solutions above

Comment: Thank you so much! You're the best! I actually needed the javascript library and using the link you posted, I found it (I guess it's written by the author): https://simplestatistics.org/docs/#ckmeans

Comment: oh great! Ya I love this algorithm. I'm really curious as to why scikit learn hasn't added it to their set of algorithms. I've found a few packages of it, but just thought this implementation worked out nice, and he provided a visualization script with it too which I liked.

Comment: btw i'm new to python — why do we use `get_jenks_breaks(x, 2)[1]` instead of `get_jenks_breaks(x, 2)`?

Comment: if you do `get_jenks_breaks(x, 2)` you'l get a list of breaks. In this case `[0.062606, 0.129939, 0.457039]`, so it will always return the min and max. and then all the breaks in between. For our purposes, we want to apply the clusters that are above/below the 2nd value (in python, that is index 1). which is why you see `[1]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191107/discussion-between-dmitry-paranyushkin-and-chitown88).

Comment: I just wanted to store that single value to be used in `if bc < breaking_point:` If that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The first two values always end up in another class than the ones starting at index 3, because they lie below the mean of ~0.152703. Since your question can also be interpreted as a simple two class problem you could also separate the two classes by using the median of ~0.0790725:

```
idx = df['bc'] > df['bc'].median()
```

Now you can use this indices to select your two classes, that are separated by the median:

```
df[idx]
```

Gives

```
        node        bc  cluster

  1  russian  0.457039        1
 48      man  0.286875        1
155    woman  0.129939        0
  3      bit  0.092721        0
```

And

```
df[~idx]
```

gives

```
     node        bc  cluster

 5  write  0.065424        0
98    age  0.064347        0
97  escap  0.062675        0
74   game  0.062606        0
```

Comment: Thank you! This is also a good and simple solution. However, I actually have a dataset of about 150 nodes, so the `median` is then much lower.

Comment: If you want to manually set your threshold you simply have to replace `df['bc'].median()` by an arbitrary number. I would'nt say that the median would be much lower. In fact I'd argue that it would stay about the same, somewhere at ~0.063, if your given data is representative and can be extrapolated.

Answer (score 0):

Just choose the threshold yourself.

It's not appropriate to hack the algorithm until you get the desired result.

If you want the first five terms to be a cluster, then just label them as you like. Don't pretend it is a clustering result.